# Adding white status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, ios10

I'm trying to add a white status bar to my ViewController like that:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

but it doesn't work in most of the views (it worked on some)

Any idea how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a pattern to which views it is not working for? I've found to change it for a navigation controller or tab bar controller you have to subclass and add the code to the subclass.

Comment: @chickenparm Yes its about navigation controller. So I have to subclass it in order to change the status bar color?!

Comment: I just added an answer with my suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UINavigationController as below. Then in interface builder set the class of your navigation controller to "MyNavigationController.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
  override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .LightContent
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set white status bar do the follwing steps:

1. Add new key "status bar style" in info.plist
2. Set the  status bar style value to "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent" in info.plist.

Refer below screen shot:

[image]

OR

1.select project target.

2.goto info tab.

3.Add new key "status bar style"

4.Set the  status bar style value to "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent".

Refer below screen shot:
[image]

Comment: @FS.O6 Have you added in projects info.plist correctly because i have created just before posting answer and its working for me.

Comment: @FS.O6 i have updated the answer check it. if you are following above steps no need to write single line of code. (This i done in xcode 7.3.1)

Comment: @FS.O6 VCs inside a navigation controller means?